# Uninstall Wordpress

Tags: ubuntu, wordpress

I am still at the beginning and just wondering how to uninstall totally WordPress and then reinstall it. 
I installed first time from [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-14-04) tutorial.

Comment: I'm sure arzyfex wanted to say `DROP DATABASE wordpress`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. go to your html folder

   cd /var/www/html

check current files in the html folder using ls command

```
ls
```

delete wordpress installation folder from there . 
you can use terminal to do that.

```
sudo rm -rf *
```

remember -rf forcefully delete all sub-directories . 
-r > remove the entire directory and all its contents, including subdirectories.

f -> force delete ( only if you need ) .

and `*` delete is saying "delete all " so be carefull when you perform these actions . 
I just add `*` assuming you don't have any other files inside html folder other than wordpress installation.

or you can open nautilus there using

```
sudo nautilus .
```

and delete all files there , make sure to not delete other folders if you have any .other than wordpress installation files.

delete database from mysql .

goto mysql using

```
mysql -u root -p
```

it will prompt asking password . type your mysql password if you have any added when you install mysql . else just press enter without password .

check your databases using

```
show databases;
```

and find your database in this case i assume it is call "wordpress"

drop it using

```
drop database wordpress;
```

it will prompt successful message .

thats all .

when you install wordpress next time in your localhost , be sure to install inside to folder . not directly into /var/www/html

you can achieve that by

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/html/wordpress
```

and move to wordpress when you moving

```
sudo rsync -avP ~/wordpress/ /var/www/html/wordpress
```

let us know if you have any trouble.

Answer (score 1):

- *Make sure you keep backup before doing this.* find folder called `wordpress` in `/var/www` and delete them using `rm -rf` or if you have extracted the content of wordpress in `/var/www` then simply remove contents of `/var/www/html/`.
- If you have installed wordpress using `apt-get` then use `sudo apt-get purge wordpress`.
- remove the database from mysql using `DROP DATABASE wordpress`.
- then follow the procedure to install.